# Struggle to kick off my first program in Python using netbeans

Tags: python, netbeans, plot

I am trying to run my first major program in python, using NetBeans. But nothing happens.

```
import numpy
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator,DateFormatter
ticker = 'AAPL'
begdate = datetime.date(2012, 1, 2)
enddate = datetime.date.today()
month = MonthLocator(range(1,13),bymonthday=1, interval=1)
monthFmt = DateFormatter("%b '%Y")
x = quotes_historical_yahoo(ticker,begdate,enddate)
if len(x) == 0:
    print ('SIAF35 - Found No Quote')
    raise SystemExit
dates = [q[0] for q in x]
closes = [q[4] for q in x]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(dates, closes, '_')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(month)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthFmt)
ax.autoscale_view()
ax.grid(True)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
fig.show()
```

Above is the code that I am trying to use. I used it in IDLE and it worked, but I would like to use it in Netbeans, so I can amend it as much as I want. Help please.

Comment: Do you get some kind of error?

Comment: Hi Lourens, not at all, nothing happens.